# "SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.category" executando rake db:migrate com a Gem Acestry

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, gem

Estou com uma dificuldade para utilizar a gem [Acestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) na parte em que diz:

> Add index to migration: add_index [table], :ancestry (UP) / remove_index [table], :ancestry

Estou criando um método chamado `Category` e tentando adicionar o Acestry mas aparece o seguinte erro no PowerShell:

> ==  AddAncestryToCategory: migrating ==========================================
>   -- add_column(:categories, :ancestry, :string)
>      -> 0.0140s
>   -- add_index(:category, :ancestry)
>   rake aborted!
>   An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.category: CREATE  INDEX "index_category_on_ancestry" ON "category" ("ancestry
>   ")C:/Sites/projetos/mymoney/db/migrate/20140205153511_add_ancestry_to_category.rb:4:in `change'
>   C:in`migrate'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Segue o código dos migrates:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

E

```
class AddAncestryToCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :categories, :ancestry, :string
    add_index :category, :ancestry
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do `add_index`, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index
A nome da tabela é passada no plural, portanto acho que se você mudar o exemplo para `add_index :categories, :ancestry`, irá funcionar normalmente.